# change Fontawesome icon with Jquery

Tags: jquery, font-awesome

I would like to change the arrow style on click.

When the accordion is closed, the arrow is down. When the user clicks the down arrow the accordion will open and the arrow will turn point up.

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm " onclick="changeToggle(this)"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down" ></i></button> 


function changeToggle(btn) {
 $(btn).closest("tr").next().toggle();     
 $(btn).removeClass('fa-arrow-down').addClass('fa-arrow-up');
}
```

Normally in jQuery, if i know the id of the parent item I could use `$("#id  i")` but because I used `this` as a parameter in the code.

I'm not sure how I can access the  inside the button to change arrow style.

Comment: `find()` is pretty niffty when you are trying to find children elements

Comment: You can use `$(btn).find('.fa')` to find the child element.

Comment: @Taplar I realized that

Comment: what about `$(btn > i)`

Comment: `btn` is an Element, not a string

Comment: btn implies the accessor for that button it's id, class etc.

Comment: No, it doesn't imply anything in the invalid command you gave.  At best it was pseudocode

Comment: `function changeToggle(){
$(this > i).removeClass("fa-arrow-down").addClass("fa-arrow-up")
}`

Comment: `$(this > i)` is an invalid selector.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to find the nested `.fa` of the button.  You can use the context version of the `$()` for that, and then just toggle the classes back and forth.

```js
function changeToggle (btn) {
  $('.fa', btn).toggleClass('fa-arrow-down fa-arrow-up');
}
```

```css
.fa-arrow-down { color: red; }
.fa-arrow-up { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm " onclick="changeToggle(this)"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down">text for easy change</i></button>
```

Comment: that's toggling button's class not updating font awesome icon

Comment: Because I did not include the font awesome library.  It is, however, showing the class updates because the text changes colors.

Comment: better update this and include font awesome from cdn

Comment: I gave an id to font awesome "Fawsm" updated a little bit like this: $(btn).find("#Fawsm").toggleClass('fa-arrow-down fa-arrow-up'); and it is working.  Thank you Taplar.

Comment: @AliAzra better use `$('#Fawsm').toggle(...)`, directly

Comment: Hi Aarif, I would love to use it directly but I have got the same button in each row and don't know which one user clicked. This is why i used btn

Comment: If you are repeating the id, then I would advise against that, as it is non-web compliant html.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page